# How to fill polygon which points are clearing after drawing another

Tags: java, algorithm

I am implementing scanline algorithm, which is supposed to fill a polygon with the color I set in the parameter. It works perfectly, however, another parameter of the algorithm is a `List` of `Points`. Here I call the `polygon.getPoints()` method, which gets me the points of the last polygon drew. This way I can only fill the last polygon.

```
if(tool == 4){

                       rasterImage = scanLine.fill(rasterImage,polygon.getPoints(),0x77a345);
                       panel.repaint();

                   }
```

**This is the RasterizePolygon() method**

You can see that the points of the polygon are kept in a list here.

```
 public RasterImage<PixelType> rasterizePolygon(RasterImage<PixelType> img,
                                               final double startX, final double startY, final PixelType value){
    RasterImage<PixelType> result = img;

        if(isDrawing == false){
            points.clear();
        }

        points.add(new Point((int) startX, (int) startY));

        if(isDrawing == true) {
            if ((points.get(points.size() - 1).x >= points.get(0).x - 10) && (points.get(points.size() - 1).x <= points.get(0).x + 10) &&
                    (points.get(points.size() - 1).y >= points.get(0).y - 10) && (points.get(points.size() - 1).y <= points.get(0).y + 10)) {

                isDrawing = false;
            }

        }

    return result;

}
```

As you can see, I am clearing the List of points after I finish drawing the polygon. That way I can start drawing another by adding new Points to the list. However, I want to be able to draw another polygon but fill even the previous one. How to implement this?

Comment: The only thing we can see is that your question is at least confused: not clear what you asked for and the given code doesn't help much. Rephrase and include more complete code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code (see @Jean-BaptisteYunès's comment for the link) and accurately describe the problem.